# It says "nothing to record" when I press record button in Motionbuilder.

Tags: autodesk

Hello I want to make a video output of my motioncapture in motionbuilder however when I press  record button in Transport controls section it says nothing to record. Can you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a video render of your mocap? Use File>Render then.

To use Record on the transport control you have to have a Device in the scene which can record  some input.